# Button orders have different top-margin, even though they have the same css file

Tags: html, css, margin

```
<a href="wordGenerator.html">
    <h3 class="box">Word Generator</h3>
</a>

<a href="todo.html">
    <h3 class="box">To-do list</h3>
</a>
<a href="calculator.html">
    <h3 class="box" >Calculator</h3>
</a>
```

when I run the code, one of the links appear with different colour and in CSS top-margin of the one with different colour is lightly lower than the rest

Comment: I think you are seeing :visited state of the link - it happens when you already went by that link, see more on [MDN about :visited state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited)

Comment: Could you reproduce your problem in a code snippet? (hit ctrl-m in question editor)